# share point Page layout AJAX

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, page-layout, ajax

I have the follwing code

```
$.ajax({

            type: "POST",
            url: "/_Catalogs/MasterPage/GDetail.aspx/GetFundURL",

            data: "{'cusip': '" +$('#<%= ddlShareClasses.ClientID %>').val() + "'}",

            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",

            dataType: "json",

            success: function (message) {

                $("#sample").html(message.d);
                alert(message.d);

            }, error: function (message) {

                $("#sample").html(message.d);
            }
            });
```

Bloew is my Label

```
<asp:Label id="sample" runat="server"/`>
```

I want to bind message.d to label. with above code i can message have some url in alert but i am unable bind it

note: message.d is a hyperlink

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that everything else is working and you get a valid JSON response, your `success` handler needs to be tweaked a bit. Because your label is a server-side control its `id` on the client will not be "sample." As a result, your jQuery selector will fail to select your label in the DOM. The selector should be something like this:

```
$('#<%= this.sample.ClientID %>');
```

Comment: Which part, the service call itself or the setting of the label tag's HTML?

Comment: setting of the label. I can see the output in alert but i want to attach output to a label. when ever dropdown changes label value need to changed

Comment: What is the output in the alert when you alert on message.d? Also, test your label selector by checking the length of the resulting jQuery object: `alert($('#<%= this.sample.ClientID %>').length);` We need to figure out if it's your selector or something to do with the value of message.d.

Comment: $("#<%=lbKiidsUrl.ClientID%>").html(message.d.find("span:first").attr("onclick", "void(0)").addClass('confirmleave'));                   i did above code but confirm leave script is not calling when i clicked on label? can you please tell me what i am doing wrong here

Comment: A couple things: a) where did `lbKiidsUrl` come from? b) you still haven't provided the raw value of `message.d`after a successful service call. I'm assuming that `message.d` is a string of HTML as your jQuery code is attempting to both attach an `onclick` attribute and add a CSS class to the first `span` tag. jQuery selectors run against jQuery objects, not raw HTML. Try to parse the HTML into a jQuery object first: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9551230/jquery-selectors-on-a-html-string

Comment: $("#<%=lbKiidsUrl.ClientID%>").html(message.d);
                $("#<%=lbKiidsUrl.ClientID%>").find("span:first").attr("onclick", "void(0)").addClass('confirmleave'); is this will work ??

Comment: message.d has text with href control in it . lbKiidsUrl is a label

Comment: Assuming `message.d` is a valid HTML string, yes that should work. If you wanted to do it all in one line you could use `append` (since your HTML string is now a jQuery object): `$("#<%= lbKiidsUrl.ClientID %>").append($(message.d).find("span:first").attr("onclick", "void(0)").addClass('confirmleave'));`

Comment: Minor correction: `append` also supports HTML strings: http://api.jquery.com/append/. However, to perform your manipulations on the HTML you'd still need a jQuery object.

Comment: its not working

Comment: I'm going to need more information than "it doesn't work." Which part? Does "message.d has text with href control in it" mean that if you alert on `message.d` you'd get something like "`<a href="#">Link</a>`"?

Comment: if i write like this $("#<%=lbKiidsUrl.ClientID%>").html(message.d); its working and i also have some message like sampletext < a href="http://testlink/{0}/{1}.pdf">click here</a> but when i am trying to add confirm class dynamically. I can' t see label on the output